# Can't get the apos.pages.find(req).slug() to work

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I try to make an apos.pages.find to show tagged articles in the current page children.

The find method works with tag, but when I try to limit the search with a slug option, it does not match.

First I tried with a

```
apos.pages.find(req).slug("/ils-parlent-de-nous")
```

but I get this error :

```
  .slug("/")
          ^

 TypeError: self.apos.pages.find(...).tag(...).slug is not a function
```

So I tried this syntax :

```
module.exports = {   label: 'Articles en une',   name:"liste-unes",   construct: function(self, options) {

      self.pageBeforeSend = function(req, callback) {

        self.apos.pages.find(req, { slug: { $gte: '/ils-parlent-de-nous' } } )
        .tag("la une")
        .published()
        .ancestors(true)        
        .sort(
          { createdAt: 1 }
        ).toArray(function(err, la-une) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return callback(err);
          }
          req.data.la-une = la-une;   

          console.log("* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ")
          console.log(la-une)

          return callback(null);
        });  
    }
 }};
```

Do I miss something ?

Thanks

Comment: I raised a github issue on this. TL;DR is that it doesn't work right now with generic cursors like those returned by docs.find or pages.find, but it does work with type-specific cursors returned from individual modules. 

https://github.com/punkave/apostrophe/issues/973

Comment: Thanks for your reply !
While this method will stay unavaible, I will add a sorting function, after the query result, based on my "req" infos.. 
Sorry my rough english, and thanks for this cool framework :))